# Jquery MsgBox giving error message

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am trying to implement MsgBox from this site:
http://jquerymsgbox.ibrahimkalyoncu.com/

to my web app. I followed the explainations:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Timesheets/Java/MsgBox/Scripts/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Timesheets/java/msgbox/styles/msgBoxLight.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Timesheets/Java/MsgBox/Scripts/jquery.msgBox.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<script>
function sign() {
    $.msgBox("The selection includes process white objects. Overprinting such objects is only useful in combination with transparency effects.");
    /*
    busyBox.Show();
    PageMethods.signe($("#form1").serializeArray(), getParameterByName("pn"), user, signcomp, signfail);
    */
}
</script>

<input type="button" name="okbtn" ID="okbtn" class="mybutton13" value="Test button" onclick="sign()" runat="server" />
</body>
```

but every time I click the button I get a Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'msgbox' message

Thank you all for the help

EDIT:

Firefox gives me : TypeError: $.msgBox is not a function

IE gives me Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'msgBox'

Comment: Are you sure that the js include file `jquery.msgBox.js` is being included correctly?  Does the file actually exist at that location?

Comment: I clicked on it with Firefox's source code and it gives me the page requested, so yes it is accessible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up making my own popup box to ask for password using dynamic content from Javascript

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Then I have solved that issue by replacing `$.msgBox` with `msg`. And now its working fine.

```
$('#okbtn').click(function() { 
msg({
     title:"Title goes here",
     content:"Content goes here",
     type:"Type goes here"
   });
});
```

I got the `msg` function from `jquery.msgBox.js`

Answer (score 0):

Try attaching the msgBox function to the button with a jQuery click() handler, instead of using the onClick attribute of the button tag.

Also note that the $.msgBox() takes a javascript object as a parameter, not a string.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#okbtn').click(function() { 
        $.msgBox({
            title:"Title goes here",
            content:"Content goes here"
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Tryed putting a 'B' with same result

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3c.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/loose.dtd">
<HTML xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><HEAD><TITLE>jquery.msgbox Demos</TITLE>
<META content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv=Content-Type>
<LINK rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="jquery.msgbox.css">
<SCRIPT type=text/javascript src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT type=text/javascript src="jquery.dragndrop.min.js"></SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT type=text/javascript src="jquery.msgbox.js"></SCRIPT>

<SCRIPT language=JavaScript type=text/javascript>  
$(function(){   

    $("#test1").click(function(){
        new $.msgbox('Hello world').show();
    });

    $("#test2").click(function(){
        new $.msgbox({
            width:500,
            height:500,
            title: 'Hello',
            content: 'Hello, world!',
            bgOpacity: .8
        }).show();
    });

    $("#test3").click(function(){
        new $.msgbox({
            allowDrag: false // enable drag and drop(default), disable if false
        }).show();
    });

    $("#test4").click(function(){
        new $.msgbox({
            onClose: function(){
                alert(this.titleWrap.html()); // this is refered to the object itself
            }
        }).show();
    });

    $("#test5").click(function(){
        new $.msgbox({
            autoClose: 10 // do not counting down
        }).show();  
    });

    $("#test6").click(function(){
        new $.msgbox({
            autoClose: 0 // do not counting down
        }).show().startAutoClose(10); // start counting down, support chain operations
    });

    $("#test7").click(function(){
        new $.msgbox({
            type: 'alert',
            content: 'Hello'
        }).show();
    });

    $("#test8").click(function(){
        new $.msgbox({
            onClose: function(){ alert(this.getValue()) }, // with onclose plugin
            type: 'confirm',
            content: 'Hello'
        }).show();
    });

    $("#test9").click(function(){
        new $.msgbox({
            onClose: function(){ alert(this.getValue()) },
            type: 'input',
            content: 'Enter your words:'
        }).show();
    });

    $("#test10").click(function(){
        new $.msgbox({
            //onAjaxed: function(){ alert('Loading complete') },
            type: 'ajax',   // or url 
            content: 'http://pwwang.com'
        }).show();
    });

    $("#test11").click(function(){
        new $.msgbox({
            type: 'iframe',
            content: 'http://pwwang.com'
        }).show();
    });

    $("#test12").click(function(){
        new $.msgbox({
            anim: 1  // 0, 2, no animation with other values
        }).show();
    });

    $("#test13").click(function(){
        new $.msgbox({
            showClose: false    // disable in options
        }).show();
    });

    $("#test14").click(function(){
        new $.msgbox({
            closeIcon: 'image:close.gif'  // or 'text:Close', or 'image:close.png' to display an image
        }).show();
    });
    $("#okbtn").click(function(){
        new $.msgbox({
            showClose: false    // disable in options
        }).show();
    });

});   

</SCRIPT>

<META></HEAD>
<BODY>
<input type="button" id="test1" value="1.The simplest way" /><br />
<input type="button" id="test2" value="2.With otions" /><br />
<input type="button" id="test3" value="3.Plugin dragndrop, drag and drop disabled" /><br />
<input type="button" id="test4" value="4.Plugin onclose" /><br />
<input type="button" id="test5" value="5.Plugin autoclose" /><br />
<input type="button" id="test6" value="6.Plugin autoclose, set by public function" /><br />
<input type="button" id="test7" value="7.Plugin contenttype, alert" /><br />
<input type="button" id="test8" value="8.Plugin contenttype, confirm" /><br />
<input type="button" id="test9" value="9.Plugin contenttype, input" /><br />
<input type="button" id="test10" value="10.Plugin contenttype, ajax/url" /><br />
<input type="button" id="test11" value="11.Plugin contenttype, iframe" /><br />
<input type="button" id="test12" value="12.Plugin animate, animate type 1" /><br />
<input type="button" id="test13" value="13.Plugin showclose, showClose=false" /><br />
<input type="button" id="test14" value="14.Plugin closeicon" /><br />
<input type="button" name="okbtn" ID="okbtn" class="mybutton13" value="Test button"  />
</BODY>
</HTML>
```